# PyTorch loss function that depends on gradient of network with respect to input

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to implement a loss function that depends on the gradient of the network with respect to its inputs. That is, the loss function has a term like

`sum(u - grad_x(network(x)))`

where `u` is computed by forward propagating `x` through the network.

I'm able to compute the gradient by calling

```
funcApprox = funcNetwork.forward(X)
funcGrad = grad(funcApprox, X, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(funcApprox))
```

Here, `funcNetwork` is my NN and `X` is the input. These computations are done in the loss function.

However, now if I attempt to do the following

```
opt.zero_grad()
loss = self.loss(X) # My custom loss function that calculates funcGrad, etc., from above
            
opt.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
opt.step()
```

I see the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

on the `loss.backward()` line from above.

I've tried playing around with `create_graph`, `retain_graph`, etc. but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When computing the gradient for the first time, the autodifferentiation graph is freed and you can't backward again. Have a look at the `retain_graph` and `create_graph` options in the [backward](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.backward.html#torch.Tensor.backward) and in the [grad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html) functions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I added `retain_graph=True, create_graph=True` to the `grad` call and `retain_graph=True` to the `backward` call. This runs into a different message: `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [30, 1]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!`

Comment: I have scanned my code for any `out=` and there is nothing.

Comment: The culprit appears to be a tensor I have computed earlier. I will try to resolve this.

Comment: I may be wrong, but after having given another look at your question I think you don't need to set `retain_graph=True` on the `backward` function, since you don't use the autograd graph further, after the backpropagation. Similarly, `create_graph=True` seems to be unnecessary since you don't need higher-order derivatives. Good luck!

Comment: Yup, that seems to work, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment by @aretor, setting `retain_graph=True, create_graph=False` in the `grad` call in the loss function, and `retain_graph=True` in `backward` solves the issue.

Comment: Why the `retain_graph` in `backward` is necessary?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure either. It made the code work and the network ended up computing the right thing (verified against an analytic solution). I haven't looked at this problem for a while now but I plan to revisit it soon again. I'll try to update you if I gain some more insight into this.